# Scipy hierarchial clustering - clusterize new vector

Tags: python, numpy, vector, scipy

I am clusterizing a bunch of feature vectors using scipy `linkage` with `ward` method.

I want a predictive model that works in two steps:

1. Training data is clusterized
2. A new vector comes, the distance between the vector and each cluster is computed, the new vector is assigned the "nearest" cluster's label

How can I compute the distances between a new vector and precomputed clusters?

Answer (score 0):

Use the euclidean metric? I think the precomputed clusters have a center. So you can calculate the distanc between every center and the new vector.

Comment: I don't think linkage returns cluster centers. Should I compute them myself?

Comment: Yes, i think that will be the best way. You could save the every center vector. Then you add a vector, you only have to update the center vector of the affected clusters.